# Fixed Background Scrolling Effect for UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, scroll, uipageviewcontroller

I've an instance of `UIPageViewController` in my project with an iPhone picture showing different sceneries as user scrolls.

I want a "fixed-background scrolling layout" i.e when the user scrolls, the iPhone-picture should remain fixed but only the sceneries inside it should change. How could I do that?

For example: In https://sdslabs.co/#muzi, as you scroll down the Mac-picture is fixed but the picture inside it changes. 
Another example can be seen in the 'Numerous' iOS app.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you know how to implement UIPageViewController. I am just explaining how to design your Layout to achieve this.

In your **FirstViewController's** View add a UIImageView containing iPhone's background in which your images will change on scrolling. Add another UIView as a sibling of your UIImageView and add ContainerView in it. Your **PageViewController** will be embedded in your Container View.

[image: Here is its UI Representation.]